# How to create an Asynchronous Script Component in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, script-component

I might be blind, but I don't see how to CREATE the script component. I'm not asking why do an asynchronous, how to work with it, etc. I just want to know how to add it to my package, or how to transform an already existing component into an asynchronous one!

I'm using VS2008 with MSSQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 4):

I found how :

1. Go in the Script Transformation Editor
2. Select "Inputs and Outputs" from the leftmost part of the screen.
3. Select your Output.
4. Set "SynchronousInputID" to "None".

Thanks to [this site](http://bi-tch.blogspot.com/2008/02/ssis-synchronousasynchronous-script.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx)

First bullet point under "Configuring Inputs, Outputs, and Output Columns"

> Set the SynchronousInputID property of each output to zero to indicate
>   that the output does not simply pass through data from an upstream
>   component or transform it in place in the existing rows and columns.
>   It is this setting that makes the outputs asynchronous to the input.

Comment: I already read that, but I don't see the "Click here to set it to asynchronous" part.

Comment: Yup, you should have your eyes examined ;)

Comment: Docs would be clearer if they say "set the property to None" instead of zero.